# Can we deduce that $\mu(X)\leq \mu(Y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ergodic-theory

> Given a measurable function $f: X \to Y$, if $f$ is injective and measure-preserving that $\mu(f(A))=\mu(A)$ for all subsets $A$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure, can we deduce that $\mu(X)\leq \mu(Y)$?

Do we have $\mu(f(X))=\mu(X)\leq \mu(Y)$ since $f(X)\subset Y$?

Comment: It ia not right to make  a basic change in the question after an answer is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question now very different from the one for which I posted this answer.

$\mu(X)=\mu (f^{-1}(Y))=\mu (Y)$ so you have equality.

Comment: How about if $f$ measure-preserving for a point?

Comment: Do we have $\mu(f(X))=\mu(X)\leq \mu(Y)$ since $f(X)\subset Y$?

Comment: That would be correct provided $f(X)$ is measurable. If $f$ is measurable and one-to-one there is no guarantee that $f(X)$ is measurable.

Comment: How about a weaker condition that $f$ is injective?